# Переход на на новую строку в табличной верстке

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, табличная-верстка

Имеется табличный блок, внутри которого заполняются данные с БД.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы в каждой строке данные заполнялись по 2 колонки одинковой высоты, то есть если соседний блок больше по высоте, другой под него подстраивался?

Вот как на картинке:

[image: Описание как должно выглядеть]

Я знаю что добиться такого результата можно с помощью `display: table` и `display: table-cell` и на основе этого прописал следующие свойства:

```
.content-table {
    display: table;
    width:   100%;
}

.content-table-cell {
    display:         table-cell;
    width:           50%;
    vertical-aling:  top;
}
```

Но как я понял это не правильно, так как он генерирует всё в одной строке..

[image: Как получется]
Как решить данную проблему? Надо по 2 блока каждой строке и желательно одинаковой высоты, так как использование `col-md-6` у бутстрапа высота блоков различается и контент может перепрыгивать с места на место...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо таблицы можно использовать простой блок:

```
.content-table {
    display: block;
    width:   100%;
}
```

А табличной ячейки `inline-block`, а для выравнивания по высоте использовать `height`

```
.content-table-cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width:   45%;   /* 50% */
    float:   left;
    height:  120px; /*Для выравнивания высоты у каждого блока*/
}
```

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: Я забыл оговорить что мне высоты одинаковые нужны у каждого элемента в зависимости от строки, то есть чтобы контент не прыгал) вот тут он прыгает..

Comment: так добавте  в  .content-table-cell  {height:400px}    если решение помогло поставте как верный ответ чтоб другие  люди не задавали его повторно а могли ознакомится уже с готовым ответом

Comment: Заработало! Дополни ответ этим я приму его :) Я знаю что надо принять ответ)

Comment: да принял  твое изменение

Comment: Спасибо) Очень простое было решение) Теперь буду знать)